# Which expansion set has more legendary cards?

Tags: hearthstone

As you might know, there are 3 sets (Grand Tournament, Normal and Goblins vs Gnomes) in Hearthstone, not including adventures like League of Explorers.

How many unique legendary cards are there in each of these sets? I mean, how many cards are there in these sets, without considering their unpack chance.

Comment: By packs, you mean "Expansions". A "pack" is a group of 5 cards that you open by either winning it or buying it. Changing the lingo here might clear up any confusion.

Comment: @ChaseC I mean packs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There are 92 collectible Legendary cards: 33 in the Classic set (1 per class and 24 neutral), 20 in the Goblins vs Gnomes set (1 per
>   class and 11 neutral), 20 in The Grand Tournament set (1 per class
>   except 2 for Hunter and 10 neutral), 6 in the Naxxramas set (all
>   neutral), 5 in the Blackrock Mountain set (all neutral), 5 in the
>   League of Explorers set (all neutral), 1 in the Reward set (neutral),
>   and 2 in the Promotion set (both neutral).

This information was taken directly from this page on the wiki: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Legendary#Legendary